# Error when compiling flutter app to android device

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I am trying to build a flutter app to an android device, I get the following error message:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Building it on an IOS simulator works fine.
My pubspec.yaml file looks like this:
name: medical_management_app
description: A new Flutter project.

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # firebase
  cloud_firestore: 0.13.0+1
  # BLoC
  flutter_bloc: ^3.0.0
  # equatable
  equatable: ^1.0.1
  # ios style icons
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I found that this error has already appeared for android devices earlier this year for apps using firebase.

Does anyone know if this error is caused by an update to the firebase packages? Or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did u try flutter clean

Comment: Now the build doesn't cause an error, but does not finish.

Comment: In terminal the last output that is produced when I use flutter run -v is: [+1055 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 1 stopped Daemons could not be
reused, use --status for details

Comment: Is this a normal output?

Comment: add firebase_core: 0.3.1+1 to your pubspec.yaml has temporarily resolved this issue

Comment: ty, removing firebase_analytics solved it as well

Answer (score 0):

Please check Step 3 this page;

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

You need to make a little change to the build gradle file for Android.